# Tkinter window showing incorrectly (entry not shown)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from functools import partial
from random import randint
from tkinter import *

def click3(a,b, c):
    if int(a) == b:
        c.delete(0.0, END)
        c.insert(END,"That's correct!")
    elif int(a) < b:
        c.delete(0.0, END)
        c.insert(END,"A bit higher")
    elif int(a) > b:
        c.delete(0.0, END)
        c.insert(END,"A bit lower")

gtnCorrect = randint(1,1000)
gtnWin = Tk()
gtnWin.title("Guess the number")
gtnWin.configure(bg='black')
Label(gtnWin, text = "Guess a number from 1-1000", bg='black',fg='white',font = '10').grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
gtnGuess = Entry(gtnWin, width = 10, bg='white')
gtnGuess.grid(row = 1,column=0,sticky=W)
op = Text(gtnGuess, width = 20, height = 1, wrap=WORD,background='white')
op.grid(row = 2, column = 0,sticky=W)
part2 = partial(click3, gtnGuess.get(),gtnCorrect,op)
Button(gtnWin, text = "Submit", width = 6, command = part2).grid(row = 3,column=0,sticky=W)
```

Hi everyone.

This part of my code isn't working properly and I'm wondering if anyone knows why. When I run it, the entry box doesn't show, only the label, text box and submit button.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are placing `op` inside of `gtnGuess`. The entry *is* displayed, it's just that it is filled with a text widget.

You need to change the parent/master of `op` to be something besides `gtnGuess`. Perhaps you meant to use `gtnWin`?